# C# using VC++2010 property sheet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, propertysheet

We store version numbers for our software in a vc++2010 property sheet.  I have 2 C# projects that need to access these numbers.  Is there a way to reasonably do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below are some of the information for your reference:-

I usually keep Property Sheets in root directory of solution (i.e. trunk/ directory in SVN repository):

```
/projectA/projectA.vsprops    
/projectA/library1
/projectA/library2
/projectA/app1
```

Sometimes I have number of Property Sheets divided by subject, for instance `boost-svn.vsprops`, `xercexs-2.8.vsprops`, etc. and combine them together according to what I need for a project.

You do not need to edit every project, but you do need to add particular Property Sheet to every project in solution.

In Visual Studio 2010 `Tools -> Options` have been [replaced with Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=454471) and this is the file where machine-wide settings should go. So, in your case I would put the SMS SDK settings to Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user file on ever developer's machine. It would also give developers flexibility to install the SDK in different location (i.e. drive) on their machine and also free your solution/projects from maintaining environment-specific settings.